# Monotonic bijection from positive reals to reals between 0 and 1

Tags: real-analysis

While engaging in personal study with regards to metric spaces I wished to construct a metric space of sequences.  As a part of this I need a function that normalized positive reals into the range between 0 and 1.  The idea being that I can define my metric as.

$ d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f( |x_n - y_n| )10^{-n} $

I don't see any reason why such a function shouldn't exist but I cannot think of one.

Comment: You could use something resembling the function $1/x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphism"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Likely an order isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x} $.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple functions that can do this with slight modifications, including arctan and 1/x.

Shifting $R^+$ to $R^{>1}$ by $x\to x+1$ will work for $1/x$, giving us $\frac{1}{x+1}$

Arctan just needs to be scaled to fit in the range: $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x)$

Comment: I thought of 1/X but 1/X is outside my codomian when X< 1

Comment: That's what the composition I mentioned is for. $x\to x+1$ moves R^+ to R>1, so then you can apply it. I'll edit to make this clearer

Comment: @QthePlatypus is that clearer

Answer (score 0):

$$\quad\frac2\pi\arctan\quad$$