# Show that $(0,1)$ and set of positive real numbers are equivalent sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I try to prove that the open interval $(0,1)$  and $\mathbb{R}_+$ are equivalent sets.

I thought maybe if I define a bijective function between those two sets; it would help, but I couldn't. Can you help with it?

Comment: Which functions did you try?  There is an obvious example which almost works and needs a slight adjustment to actually work

Comment: You can find some bijections here: [Monotonic bijection from positive reals to reals between 0 and 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631521/monotonic-bijection-from-positive-reals-to-reals-between-0-and-1).

Comment: Please do not roll back improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

$$f(x):(0,\infty)\to (0,1)\;,\;\;f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\;\ldots$$

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer.I may have misrepresented it. Find a bijective function between this sets to prove they are equal is just a way that i thought. Actually I need to prove that they are equal step by step.

Comment: Well, there you have it! Prove the above function is bijective and thus invertible, and thus both sets are equipotent...because when you write "equal" I guess you actually mean "equipotent = have the same cardinal".

Answer (score 2):

Try  $f:(0,1)\to(0,\infty)$ by $f(t)=\tan(π/2t)$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f:(0,1)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=x/(1-x) $  proves the equivalence.
$f$ is 1-1: Easy to check.

$f$ is onto:  For every $y\in (0,\infty)$ there exists $x=y/(1+y) $ such that $f(x)=y.$

f is continuous and $f^{-1}:y\rightarrow y/(1+y)$ is also continuous.

Hence proved! Complete the 1-1 part!

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer.I may have misrepresented it. Find a bijective function between this sets to prove they are equal is just a way that i thought. Actually I need to prove that they are equal step by step.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by step by step.  This answer seems fine.